# APNS PHP JSON Payload structure

Tags: php, json, nested, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notifications via a PHP script to connect to APNS server. Everything is working fine when I use the below payload structure.

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'badge' => $badge,
    'sound' => 'default'

    );

$payload = json_encode($body);
```

However, I need to add more parameters to the 'alert' element as well as want to add some more custom parameters. The way I do is is as follows, but APNS is not accepting the JSON. Is it a problem with my JSON creation method in PHP?

```
$payload='{

"aps": {
    "alert":{
    "title": "'.$message.'",    
    "body":"'.$notif_desc.'"
            },
"badge":"'.$badge.'",
"sound": "default"


},
"type": "notification",
"id":"'.$lastid.'",
"date:"'.$date1.'"

}';
```

So basically, I have two queries. IS the second method wrong? If so, please show me a valid method to create nested JSON Payload for APNS server. Second question, I need to add custom PHP variables to the Payload, I want to know whether the way I have added it in the second method is right or wrong.

basically, I need to create a JSON object as below in PHP

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a double quote after the "date" property:

```
"date:"'.$date1.'"
```

... should be...

```
"date":"'.$date1.'"
```

I'd recommend putting the payload together as a PHP object/array first (like your original example) as it is *much* easier to see the structure in that format rather than a giant concatenated string. E.g.

```
$payload['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'action-loc-key' => 'PLAY'
    ),
    'badge' => $badge,
    'sound' => 'default'
);
$payload['acme1'] = 'bar';
$payload['acme2'] = array(
    'bang',
    'whiz'
);

$payload = json_encode($body);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. The thing was that, I was missing the double quote after date. And I am a little awkward with the JSON, so I think your suggestion about using  PHP object/array is what I am going to use. Thanks Brother !!!

Comment: No problem. Making a big string definitely makes it harder to read. Good luck with your coding!  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$send_data = 
array(
        'aps' => 
        array
        (
            'status_code'=>200,
            'alert'=>$message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'notification_type'=>'DoctorPendingRequest',
            'request_id'=>$request_id
        )
);
```

Passs $send_data to payload.

Comment: I need another nesting inside the alert element. How do I do that?

Comment: @AshifShereef The code shown in the other answer should work for you.